# Codeshare between a point-to-point LCC and a FSC - one / two tickets?

Tags: tickets, connecting-flights, code-share, low-cost-carriers, split

Low-cost carriers (LCC) usually use a point-to-point system that doesn't allow connecting flights and you will have separate tickets for each flight. But some LCCs have codeshare with full-service carriers (FSC).
In this case, if I travel with two flights:
operating LCC, codeshare FSC
operating FSC, codeshare LCC
(or any other FSC / LCC combination)
if this route is booked via FSC, will it be 1 ticket or separate tickets? Via LCC?

Comment: Your question is not really answerable without specifying the actual carriers involved. The world is not divisible into LCCs (low cost carriers) who all follow one set of rules and FSCs (full service carriers) who each follow a different set of rules. In general if a traditional full service airline sells you a journey, it will be on one ticket, or it won't sell the journey at all; but I'm sure someone can find an exception to that.

Comment: Yeah this all just really, really depends. While some European LCC's don't have any consideration of connecting flights at all, that's not universally true: AirAsia sells connecting flights on "Fly-Thru" service on certain routes; US LCC's often sell connecting flights; and some LCC's will sell connecting flights with FSC's like Vueling/British Airways or Emirates/flydubai. And the exact arrangements around whether you need to claim baggage, go through security or immigration, or check-in again may depend on the airport and route.

Comment: And of course you have FSCs who have turned into LCCs but still keep some (but not all) of their previous habits, and probably LCCs who try to act like FSCs.